# What is the correct way to use commas in this sentence?

Tags: commas, sentence

I have a hard time correctly placing commas in sentences such as the one presented below. What is the correct usage of commas here and are there any simple rules I can memorize for this?

The sentence without any commas:

- Each X is created by first choosing some number of Y and then distributing the Zs using N different approaches.

My attempt at correctly placing commas:

- Each X is created by, first, choosing some number of Y and, then, distributing the Zs, using N different approaches.

Comment: Clarity first (and this involves using standard punctuation conventions [where conventions _actually are_ standard]), then elegance. I'd use << Each X is created by first choosing some number of Y and then, using N different approaches, distributing the Zs. >> or << Each X is created by first choosing some number of Y and then distributing the Zs. N different approaches are adopted for each two-part process. >> depending on the meaning intended.

Comment: You're trying to get too much information into one sentence, and no amount of commas will suffice for infrastructure. If all you want is an official sentence, put them wherever you like; but if you actually expect people to read and understand the sentence, and use that understanding in reading on, rewrite that sentence into a paragraph with simpler sentences that can only be pronounced in a couple of ways, and follow in a logical sequence, instead of a grammatical one.